# AWS lamba function with DynamoDb. New image of item does not contain all fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda function with DynamoDb. When I edit an item in dynamodb table, the lambda function is triggered.

When I receive the new image of the item with the event inside my lambda function, some of the fields are not present in the new image dict. I only get 3 fields, whereas my dynamodb table contains 6 fields. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by disabling and re-enabling the stream on the Dynamo Db via the Manage Stream

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to re-check the DynamoDB Streams configuration.

Check the value for `StreamViewType`

When an item in the table is modified, StreamViewType determines what information is written to the stream for this table. Valid values for StreamViewType are:

Valid Values: NEW_IMAGE | OLD_IMAGE | NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES | KEYS_ONLY.

For detailed information check this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_StreamSpecification.html).

Comment: my streamviewtypes are set to send both old and new images. Yest I am getting only limited fields.

Comment: This is happening to me, were you able to fix it?

Comment: I pray at the alter of the three year old stack overflow question, and the only answer are the cackles of dead gods and broken dreams

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting and readding the stream on the lambda function.